# JPA @Embeddable inheritance with discriminator column

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use an embeddable hierarcy like:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{
   private MyEmbedded member;
}

@Embeddable
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name ="TYPE")
public abstract class MyEmbedded{
    protected String type;
}

@Embeddable
@DiscriminatorValue('1')
public class MyEmbeddedImpl1{...}

@Embeddable
@DiscriminatorValue('2')
public class MyEmbeddedImpl2{...}
```

[TopLink / EclipseLink : Support inheritance with embeddables. This is set through using a DescriptorCustomizer and the InheritancePolicy](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables#Inheritance)

How can I acomplish this with JPA and Hibernate?

Comment: Didn't found anything in hibernate docs so I've opened: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14185

Comment: Yeah I want this too. Too bad it looks like it isn't supported right now :(